# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed. How to correctly fix?

Tags: laravel

I have migration on laravel 6. I have a table for **questions** and  **answers** and I need to make a foreign key of field **best_answer_id** from table questions to **id** from table **answers**.

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->text('body');
    $table->unsignedInteger('views')->default(0);
    $table->unsignedInteger('answers')->default(0);
    $table->integer('votes')->default(0);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('best_answer_id')->references('id')->on('answers')->onDelete('SET NULL');
});

Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('question_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->integer('vote_count')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I don't know why it is not working. I am quite sure about this. Am I missing something here?

I am getting an error on the **best_answer_id** foreign key part. 
The **user_id** part has no problem.

```
General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_qa`.`questions` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have just tried using the same migrations as yours. I do get the
>   error when I run the both migrations at 1 go, some points to take care
>   while you are creating the migrations above:

- Make sure that both the migrations are created individually
- Make sure the the migration for the answers is created and run before the questions

Comment: No, those schemas are run separately . I just put that there together for comparison

Comment: Okay, so kindly run the migration for the answers before the questions, then it will work perfectly.

Comment: I didn't do anything, but suddenly it's now working. I'm scared now. lol Thank you sir.

Comment: Hehehe, happy codding :D

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error probably because you are trying to create `questions` table **before** `answers` table.

`questions` table **is dependent** on `answers` table.

So create `answers` first.

Comment: hey. yeah sorry. Actually the answers table was created first before that. So I was thinking why it is not working.

Comment: Both table are dependent to each other.

Comment: tried to put the foreign key code for the best_answer_id to another new file schema separately. And now it works. Wth. I think I need a coffee break now. btw. Thanks @linuxartisan for the response.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here:

First, you have to create an `answers` table, which means first create a migration that is not dependent on any other table.

Migrations must be created `Top-Down`.

As `best_answer_id` belongs to `answers` table, but `answer` table is not migrated yet.

Try to run this, your table will get migrated without any error.

```
Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('question_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->integer('vote_count')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->text('body');
    $table->unsignedInteger('views')->default(0);
    $table->unsignedInteger('answers')->default(0);
    $table->integer('votes')->default(0);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('best_answer_id')->references('id')->on('answers')->onDelete('SET NULL');
});
```

You can also reverse the previous migration then just simply run above one.

Comment: Thanks mate! I got the idea. But it is now working. I just sip a coffee and when I came back, it's now working. Weird. lol anyway, thanks for the tips again.

Comment: @MDB , you have also added `question_id` in answer table but your not set it as a foreign key, but if you want it as a FK, then after current migration you can set the FK and re-run.

Comment: yup. i got plans for that. I just put it there for now. Lol. thanks =)